# Error while trying to scan a document using a scanner device in macOS in the Swift/SwiftUI App

Tags: swiftui, swift3

I was wondering if there are any guidelines or examples for scanning documents with a scanner using Swift in a SwiftUI app. Scanning failed with the following error message:

```
Scanner Device has not yet become ready
```

Any guidelines will be appreciated.

I was able to browse devices using both IKDeviceBrowser and ICDeviceBrowser. Opening the session was successful too. But whenever I called requestScan or requestOverviewScan, I received that message.